# How to extract arrays from frequency tables in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a frequency table in pandas. I want to extract the frequencies of each class per level of odor into a list, with each element being a NumPy array containing the frequency count of classes for a given level of odor. How can I do this without manually specifying rows and columns?

This is what I have:

```
test=df.groupby(['odor', 'class'])
test.size()
```

Which results in:

```
odor  class
a     e         400
c     p         192
f     p        2160
l     e         400
m     p          36
n     e        3408
      p         120
p     p         256
s     p         576
y     p         576
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you've provided zero data to work with.  I'm completely guessing at what your data looks like based on the half a clue you left.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'odor': np.random.choice(list('acflmnpsy'), 100),
        'class': np.random.choice(list('ep'), 100),
        'frequency': np.random.choice(np.arange(60, 241), 100)
    }
)

df.groupby(['odor', 'class']).frequency.apply(np.array)

odor  class
a     e                             [170, 178, 67, 97]
      p                                 [183, 165, 73]
c     e                            [106, 163, 71, 171]
      p                       [72, 224, 112, 196, 134]
f     e               [134, 67, 190, 226, 74, 62, 107]
      p             [222, 74, 177, 186, 122, 120, 121]
l     e                   [81, 97, 124, 181, 101, 185]
      p                            [182, 136, 77, 190]
m     e                 [217, 121, 141, 102, 171, 106]
      p              [127, 178, 127, 72, 209, 63, 167]
n     e                   [166, 121, 79, 117, 130, 92]
      p                            [71, 136, 219, 155]
p     e            [118, 193, 147, 219, 154, 130, 169]
      p             [69, 162, 138, 193, 236, 144, 192]
s     e                                [105, 139, 143]
      p                        [72, 149, 186, 220, 63]
y     e            [143, 134, 102, 144, 186, 207, 181]
      p        [177, 215, 190, 158, 203, 157, 85, 172]
Name: frequency, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for?

df.pivot_table(index=['Class'], columns=['Odor'], value=['freq'],aggfunc='sum')